# AudioSink outside of the Sandbox malfunctioning with REDHAWK IDE

Tags: redhawksdr

When I try to use the AudioSink component design by Axios which can be downloaded from: https://github.com/Axios-Engineering/audio-components
and used as a component is not working outside of the sandbox chalkboard.

I created a SCA Waveform Project with the AudioSink as a component and when I try to launch it with the Device Manager it doesn't launch it because it can't initiate an instance of the AudioSink component.

You can create a simple waveform using 2 components: AudioTestSource and connect this one to the AudioSink and it will not let the Device manager launch the component.

Some help please.

Comment: What version of Redhawk are you using? Also, what OS / OS version? Also, have you installed the various GStreamer requirements per the audio-components webpage?

Answer (score 1):

I have tested the components running within the DomainManager in the manner you suggested and they work for me.  It will be difficult to isolate the problem without some additional information about your system and the errors you are experiencing.

Here are a few things to check first.

1. Have you installed the components into the SDRROOT?  This can be done by either dragging
   the component project in the IDE over to the Target SDR or by running "make install" in 
   the components folder.  You can confirm that they have been installed to doing `ls

   $SDRROOT\dom\components`.  In that folder you should see AudioTestSource and AudioSink.
2. When you attempt to launch the waveform; can you provide the error printout that the
   DomainMananger and DeviceManager produced?

Comment: I verified and it is installed in the dom\components.This is the error I'm getting: ERROR:DCE:5ea26756-4e0e-42ed-bb62-50c9d90c0c05:Child process 3497 terminated with signal 11
Unable to create application - make sure that all appropriate nodes are installed

Comment: Also I deleted the component from the dom\components and proceed to download the file from the this link:https://github.com/Axios-Engineering/audio-components and copied the file of the AudioSink to the workspace and build the project and drag it to the TargetSDR and it's still failing outside of the Sandbox. Could it be that a dependency is installed incorrectly? I am using a virtual machine that I received from someone else that already had REDHAWK IDE installed.

Comment: the error that is giving now is:Unable to create application - make sure that all appropriate nodes are installed
.

Comment: The `make sure all appropriate nodes are installed` seems to indicate one of two things: either your Domain doesn't have any GPP devices in it or the dependencies of the GPP don't match the dependencies of the component.  Check that you have a GPP in the Domain and can launch other components.  If that works, run the DomainManager in DEBUG level...it should tell you more details about why it failed to create the application.